# Get dates in "human readable" format

Tags: php, symfony, date, fosrestbundle

I am working in a RESTFul API using Symfony2 and FOSRestBundle. The entities use Gedmo for Timestampable options:

```
use Gedmo\Timestampable\Traits\TimestampableEntity;
```

And I get the `createdAt` as any other column:

```
$obj->getCreatedAt()
```

Then I pass that response to FOSRestBundle:

```
 $respEmail = [
        "id"                 => (string)$entEmail->getId(),
        ...
        "category"           => $entEmail->getEmailsCategory(),
        "createdAt"          => $entEmail->getCreatedAt()
 ];

 $view->setData($respEmail)->setStatusCode(200);
```

And I get this:

```
{
  "id": "5",
  ...
  "category": "sent",
  "createdAt": "2015-06-12T11:00:55-0430"
}
```

How do I fix the date? I want something like `2015-06-12 11:00:55`. Any help?

Comment: Please note that this format is the JSON Date, which is intended to be parsed on the client side. You can, of course, do what you ask for, but if you are actually developing a public API, you should leave the JSON date in the response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's a [`DateTime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) object, and I assume it is, you should be able to do:

```
$entEmail->getCreatedAt()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')
```

More information on [`DateTime::format()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.format.php)